# XSLT transform list of repeating elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do something like an iteration over element names. I'm given Input in the form of

```
<list>
    <element1>ID 1</element1>
    <element2>name 1</element2>
    <element3>town 1</element3>        
    <element4>ID 2</element4>
    <element5>name 2</element5>
    <element6>town 2</element6>
    <!-- list continues like that -->
</list>
```

Now my target scheme is supposed to look like that:

```
<newlist>
    <Person>
        <ID>ID 1</ID>
        <Name>name 1</Name>
        <Town>town 1</Town>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>ID 2</ID>
        <Name>name 2</Name>
        <Town>town 2</Town>
    </Person>
    <!-- more Persons here -->
</newlist>
```

The entries in the first list are always repeating in the same way, so what came to my mind is iterating over them and applying a modulo-operator to a loop-counter in order to figure out the right element the entry should be mapped to.
However I could not find a Transformation like this. What would be the way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 3 = 1]">
        <Person>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ID>
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
            </Name>
            <Town>
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
            </Town>
        </Person>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```